# Diagrama ER de una liga de fútbol

Tags: base-de-datos, diseño, modelorelacional, patrones-de-diseño

Necesito hacer un diagrama ER de una liga de fútbol con las siguientes 4 especificaciones:

1. Cada equipo tiene nombre, sede, fecha de creación, y fundador. El nombre del equipo tiene valor único para cada equipo.
2. El equipo tiene una plantilla de jugadores. Los jugadores pueden pertenecer a un solo equipo.
3. Cada jugador tiene una ficha de jugador (numero), nombre completo, posición y numero de camiseta. La ficha de jugador tiene valor único para cada jugador.
4. Cada partido tiene fecha y hora de inicio, y tiene dos equipos distintos que lo juegan. Además, tiene los jugadores que van a jugar el partido por equipo. Se desea registrar que jugadores jugaron el partido y en que posición. Además, se desea obtener el resultado del partido.

En la imagen verán mi intento:
[image: Stack aún no me deja poner imágenes]

Tengo, principalmente 2 dudas:

1. He creado una relación recursiva llamada `Juega_contra`; pero no le he puesto cardinalidad, creo que si la pongo como una relación varios a varios sería un error porque implicaría que dos equipo puede jugar contra 2 en la misma fecha o sede u hora, inclusive, lo que no tiene mucho sentido, tampoco creo que sea de 1 a varios, porque eso implicaría lo mismo, que un equipo puede jugar contra 2 en la misma fecha, en principio sería 1 a 1. 1 equipo sólo puede jugar contra otro en la misma fecha.
2. La relación `Juega_contra` tiene un atributo llamado `alineación`, alineación en principio sería una lista que guarda, por ejemplo, el número de ficha de todos los jugadores que estuvieron en el partido y para qué equipo juegan (porque esto podría cambiar con el tiempo), por eso lo puse como un atributo multivaluado, puede ser 0, 11 o hasta 16 si la liga permite los 5 cambios.

¿Podrían decirme cuál sería la mejor regla de cardinalidad para el punto 1 y si está bien que alineación sea multivaluado en el punto 2?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Justamente, en este sitio, no hacemos eso, porque lo pedis esta sujeto a discusiones (yo te digo que esta bien, otro te dice que esta mal, los dos tenemos razon)...

Comment: Pero si te puedo decir algo, la relacion de cardinalidad explica por cada registro de una de las tablas, cuantos registros con esa clave estan en la otra.. Por lo tanto, tenes una relacion nx1 de juega contra a equipo... hay muchos registros de partidos para cada equipo... pero un solo equipo (por relacion) para cada partido... Lo que vos describis arriba, no son reglas de cardinalidad, son reglas de negocio...

Comment: @gbianchi entendido, la modificaré.

Comment: No se que queres decir con un atributo multivaluado... e igual, sigue siendo basada en opiniones.. nadie mejor que tu profesor para corregirte esto...

Comment: @gbianchi multivaluado significa que es una lista con cualquier cantidad de elementos, por eso el doble círculo. Muchas gracias por explicar lo de la cardinalidad, no lo había entendido bien.

Comment: @gbianchi mi profesor me tiene en "visto" desde hace 4 días, jeje

Answer (score 0):

yo crearia una entidad PARTIDO que va a tener dos equipos, hora de inicio, fecha, resultado.
Con el tema de alineacion podes al crear PARTIDO crear PARTIDO_JUGADORES que tenga dos claves el id de PARTIDO y el id de EQUIPO, en esa tabla tendrias los atributos que necesitas guardar de cada jugador de cada equipo para ese partido.
Espero haber sido claro, sino preguntame. Saludos

Comment: entiendo, creo que sí haría eso a la hora de pasar el diagrama a tablas; pero nuestro profesor dijo que lo de las tablas y el diagrama son cosas "aparte" que el diseño debe ser más sencillo. En ese sentido no veo la necesidad de crear la entidad partido porque redundaría información que juega_contra ya puede almacenar.

Comment: juega contra no iria en caso de tener PARTIDO, seria el equivalente a tener JUEGA_CONTRA con dos id de EQUIPO a lo que me refiero

Comment: Esto es exactamente igual a lo que tiene descripto :/

Comment: @Pushuno muchas gracias.